# Brighness controls & touchpad multi touch not working on Asus X553MA Laptop, Xubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, drivers, xubuntu, touchpad, asus

I am new to Linux and have recently purchased an Asus X553MA laptop with a Baytrail processor and Intel HD Graphics. Unfortunately i am not able to change the brightness of the display. I have tried several commands from Ubuntu community.

I have also tried the Intel graphics installer from Ubuntu, but it couldn't find any updated drivers.
Another issue is that my touch pad multi touch features like scrolling and context menu are not working .

I have tried the following command to list input devices:

```
xinput --list
 Virtual core pointer
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer              
⎜   ↳ PS/2 Logitech Wheel Mouse                 
⎜   ↳ USB Optical Mouse
```

I have a HP mouse attached to the laptop.

How can i install the drivers for display/graphics and touchpad ?

- OS: Xubuntu 14.04, 32 bit
- Processor: Intel N3530
- Graphics: Intel HD Graphics

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be a bug that is being worked on, this link explains:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1391545

Answer (score 1):

The following may be helpful. I have worked on many systems (although not an expert with Linux). But the following is true.

Hardware built by several companies have routine problems with keyboard mapping, when using Linux. This is because problem manufacturers create a different keyboard map for each series of products. Sometimes this even extends to discreet models.

When buying the hardware from the store, or directly from the manufacturer; you receive the included Windows WITH the patches from the manufacturer. Each manufacturer, creates their own patches to overcome many problems that would be extant if Windows was installed as just the OEM distribution.

This happens because manufacturers do not standardize around a set of hardware components, or even several known sets. Some manufacturers even build their own integrated circuits which require private drivers for proper operation.

Manufacturers who are known to build their own IC's are: Lenovo, Samsung, Acer, Asus.

Manufacturers who build unique keyboard maps, year over year: anything designed by companies that exist outside the United States. This includes companies from Taiwan, Japan, South Korea, China. These companies include: Asus, Acer, Samsung, Toshiba, Lenovo, and several others.

Systems that I have found standardized their keyboard layouts: Hewlett Packard, Dell, Gateway, and a few others.

This does not mean all the function-key shortcuts work, but the important ones (volume and brightness, for example) are sure to work. Most U.S. designed system have standardized their standard peripherals around REALTEK  IC components for things like keyboard and mouse, and web-camera and some other stuff. And explains why Ubuntu can provide a better keyboard map, and the associated drivers for these systems.

Hardware drivers, not available via Ubuntu depositories can sometimes (but not always) be found on the Internet. I have found a Lenovo that did not work on WIFI or Ethernet, and both drivers were eventually found by the owner, after looking around for about 3-weeks, with a different computer. Each of these had to be installed the hard way. Instructions for installing non-standard drivers into Ubuntu (or any other Linux for that matter) is available on the Internet and via the help services in Ubuntu website.

I don't mean to sound terse, but I have become VERY disenchanted with any computers designed outside the U.S., because of the above problems. There are even some Acer systems (yours is a Asus) which have been firmware inhibited from reliably booting into Ubuntu. Luckily, Acer has gotten away from that practice, some years ago; and at this point, I have not seen that problem raise its' ugly head in a while.

I leave you with the above info, in the firm hope that you can work around the problems you are experiencing.

Have fun and good luck!